# ggplot/plotnine - adding a legend from geom_text() with specific color

Tags: pandas, ggplot2, plotnine

I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Segment': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D', 4: 'A', 5: 'B', 6: 'C', 7: 'D'},
                  'Average': {0: 55341, 1: 55159, 2: 55394, 3: 56960, 4: 55341, 5: 55159, 6: 55394, 7: 56960},
                  'Order': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 0, 5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 3},
                  'Variable': {0: 'None', 1: 'None', 2: 'None', 3: 'None', 4: 'One', 5: 'One', 6: 'One', 7: 'One'},
                  '$': {0: 40.6, 1: 18.2, 2: 78.5, 3: 123.3, 4: 42.4, 5: 24.2, 6: 89.7, 7: 144.1},
                  'ypos': {0: 96.0, 1: 55.4, 2: 181.2, 3: 280.4, 4: 96.0, 5: 55.4, 6: 181.2, 7: 280.4},
                  'yticks': {0: 20.3,1: 9.1,2: 39.25,3: 61.65,4: 21.2,5: 12.1,6: 44.85,7: 72.05}})
```

[image]

With I plot this:

```
(ggplot(df, aes(x="Segment", y="$", ymin=0, ymax=300, fill="Variable"))
 + geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = True), alpha=0.7)
 + geom_text(aes(x = "Segment", y = "ypos", label = "Average"), size=8, format_string="Average: \n ${:,.0f} CLP")
 + geom_text(aes(label = "$"), show_legend=True, position=position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size=8, format_string="%s"%(u"\N{dollar sign}{:,.0f} MM"))
)
```

[image]

I have been looking for a way to add the legend of `Average` and (then) I will delete the 'Average' words on the bars and leaving just the number. However, for this to be understandable, the additional legend should be the same color as the Average number values (could be yellow, orange, or any other, but no red or sky blue as those colors are already being used)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add color as a variable to `geom_text` :

```
import plotnine
from plotnine import ggplot, geom_col, aes, position_stack, geom_text, scale_color_brewer, guides, guide_legend

(ggplot(df, aes(x="Segment", y="$", ymin=0, ymax=300, fill="Variable"))
 + geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = True), alpha=0.7)
 + geom_text(aes(y = "ypos",color="Segment",label = "Average"), size=8, 
             show_legend=True,format_string="${:,.0f} CLP")
 + geom_text(aes(label = "$"), show_legend=True, position=position_stack(vjust = 0.5), 
             size=8, format_string="%s"%(u"\N{dollar sign}{:,.0f} MM"))
 + scale_color_brewer(type='qual', palette=2)
 + guides(color=guide_legend(title="Averages"))
)
```

[image]

Comment: And change x="Segment" to color="Segment" and leave x= in blank. It worked!